# Push to array from callback

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback

I have been tasked with completing a project in **NodeJS**, I am a novice to Node. I am trying to push to an array from a callback because I need the array for the next step, when I hit the next function after populating the array it however is not populated, I have subsequently found out that this is result of push to a array from a asynchronous function that is executed sometime in the future (something like this).

This is my code right now:

```
const input_image = process.argv.slice(2);
if (input_image.length == 0) {
    console.log('node index.js <filename>');
    return ;
}
const read_files = require('node-readfiles');
const average_color = require('image-average-color');
const color_space = require('color-space');
var db = [];
read_files('dbb', {
    filenameFormat: read_files.FULL_PATH,
    readContents: false
}, (err, filename) => {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    average_color(filename, (err, color) => {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        db.push({
            filename: filename,
            space: color_space.rgb.lab([color[0], color[1], color[2]])
        });
    });
}).catch((err) => {
   console.log('Error reading files:', err.message);
});
```

Please assist me to any resources that can help me properly push to the db array. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve your problem exactly, but [this async helper library might help you out](https://caolan.github.io/async/).

Comment: Also, the api for node-readfiles is kind of strange and confusing. I'd recommend using the built-in [`fs.readdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) instead. It'll give you an array of file names, which is more straight-forward and should play more nicely with some of the functions from that async library, like the `map` one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that might have the same problem, Read up on `Promises`.